# Dear xxx in the beginning, Sincerely, in the end for a boss?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

When I am sending an e-mail to my direct boss who are working closely for years and meet him at least once a week, is it odd to add "Dear xxx" in the beginning of e-mails, and "Sincerely," in the end? Of note, my boss is around at the age near my parents.
Typically, my boss replied Hi (my name), in the beginning, and Best, in the end. When I need to ask the boss a big favor, it might be better to use Dear and Sincerely. But except this, does Dear and Sincerely sound like an apple-polisher?

Comment: A clue might be whether you call your boss by his first name or address him as Mr ...  *Dear* and * Sincerely* are generally used for more formal relationships. But if you have to err, it's a good idea to err on the side of formality, especially if you are asking a favour.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I typically address his name as Mr. xxx. I have never called his first name in front of him. In this case, Dear Mr. xxx and then Sincerely, would be more appropriate. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. It's not wrong, and it would do no harm to use "Dear".
However, I tend not to use "Dear" when writing "internal" emails. I don't use any salutation; I just start with the content:  "Here is the report on the ...." I sign off with just my name.

I suspect you may be overthinking this. Most people have far too many emails to process each day to get upset by the presence or absence of the word "Dear".